# Как увидеть передаваемую переменную из одной формы в другую в описанной функции?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть несколько классов. В одном из классов объявлена функция, в которой ведётся обработка данных и возвращает результат:

```
QStringList MainWindow::Output()
{
    QStringList result;
    выполнение функции...;
    return result;
}
```

Далее в этом же классе вызывается вторая форма:

```
void MainWindow::on_action_triggered()
{
    ...
    table window(Output());
    ...
}
```

и на вторую форму передаётся переменная с результатом обработки функции `Output`.

На второй форме: h:

```
...
public:
    explicit table(QStringList result, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~table();
...
```

cpp:

```
...
table::table(QStringList result, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::table)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ...
}
```

И вот проблема, получается, что на второй форме (.cpp) я могу работать с переменной `result` только в `конструкторе`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно работать с данной переменной по всей области исходника, например, объявить функцию и указать там эту переменную.

Спасибо.

Comment: ¿Что мешает добавить в класс соответствующее поле?

Comment: @user7860670, правильно ли я Вас понял, что в заголовке (.h) создать ещё одну переменную в области `private:`, например: `QStringList data;`, и в конструкторе (.cpp), в теле указать `data=result;`. 

Я так сделал, у меня всё получилось.

Comment: Ну в общем да .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовке (.h) создать ещё одну переменную в области `private:`, например: `QStringList data;`, и в конструкторе (.cpp), в теле указать `data=result;`.
Теперь переменную `data` можно `увидеть` по всей области класса.

Comment: Осталось только выпустить ролик с заголовком "ШОК! Я Был приятно удивлен этой возможностью C++! Нужно всего лишь..."

Comment: @gbg, "отличная" идея.

Answer (score 2):

Главное правило работы с формами в Qt - создавать их динамически.

Второе правило работы с Qt - использовать сигналы и слоты для обмена данными между формами.

Работать это может как-то так:

```
class FormAlpha
{
signals:
   void doFormBeta(const QString& data1,const QString&  data2,const QString&  data3);
};


FormAlpha::actionWonder()
{
    doFormBeta("pip", "pop", "bop");
}

class FormBeta
{
public slots:
   void proceedFormBeta(const QString& data1,const QString&  data2,const QString&  data3)
    {
         //do all business
    }
};
```

Обе формы создать динамически, соединить их сигнал и слот - и получится аккуратно.

```
auto alpha = new FormAlpha();
auto beta = new FormBeta();

connect(alpha, SIGNAL(doFormBeta(тут параметры)), beta, SLOT(processFormBeta(тут параметры)));
```

Код очень условный (без IDE писать на Qt, как оказалось, тяжеловато), но надеюсь, идею вы извлечете.

Comment: Спасибо за идею. В будущем обязательно воспользуюсь. Но в данный момент проект не переделываемый. Работаем с чем имеется.